# Most recent version of SQL Server Management Studio that works with Windows 7 pre SP1?

Tags: sql-server-2008, installation, windows-7, ssms

I am trying to do some work with SQL Server 2008 (not 2008 r2, just 2008) that is installed on a Windows 7 Pro 32-bit PC. It's just Windows 7 with no Service Pack 1 applied. I have no option to update the PC, can only use it as it is now.

I am trying to find a version of SQL Server Management Studio that will install on this PC. Does anyone know?

I tried v17.9.1 but I got an error saying that Win 7 SP1 is required. Unfortunately I have no option to install SP1 and the computer has no access to the internet either.

What was the last version that DID install on just plain Windows 7?

Cheers.

Comment: The fact that you are using Windows 7 is an issue; the fact you don't have SP1 installed makes it an even bigger problem... SP1 came out **13 years** ago. This sounds like a PC that has been starved of updates since it was built...

Comment: You could try version 16 (it's still available for [download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-ver16#previous-ssms-releases)). Otherwise you may well need to find your installation media for SQL Server 2008 and install SSMS 2008.

Comment: As a note, even SSMS 17.0 required [Windows 7 SP1](https://web.archive.org/web/20170504141916/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms) as a minimum.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I know it's crazy but it's an old system operating without any network connectivity. How can I confirm the system requirements for Version 16.5.3? I can't find any mention on the internet. Need to know if it will install on plain Win 7 Pro 32-bit.

Comment: I couldn't find it. SSMS 17 (and 18) work on all supported Windows OSes, and support SQL Server 2008+ so the one to use is that one in Microsoft's eyes (and I don't blame them).

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to download SSMS from the installation media for  **Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 SP2 - Express Edition** which at the time of this posting is still available [from this link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30438).

I chose to only download the file: `SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe`

When I installed it I chose "New Installation" and not "Existing Installation" which apparently won't work.

I also tried to install SSMS 16.5.3 but it did not work, it also requires Win 7 SP1 if installing that version in Win 7.

I still don't know what is the most recent version of SSMS that will install in Win 7 (minus SP1).